# NIO byte Buffer has empty bytes when ready to read

Tags: nio, bytebuffer

I am writing an NIO server, right now to test I am connecting to myself, i have it written to where the client sends a handshake protocol and the server has to respond but when i try to read the handshake all i get are empty bytes from the byte buffer even though there is data waiting to be read. I have attached the protocol code below

```
public class HooMENodeProtocol implements TCPProtocol {

private int bufSize; // Size of I/O buffer

/**
 * initializes buffer size
 * @param bufSize the size of the byte buffer
 */
public HooMENodeProtocol(int bufSize) {
    this.bufSize = bufSize;
}

/**
 * accepts incoming network connections
 */
public void handleAccept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel clntChan = ((ServerSocketChannel) key.channel()).accept();
    clntChan.configureBlocking(false); // Must be nonblocking to register
    // Register the selector with new channel for read and attach byte buffer
    clntChan.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ, new HooMEAttachment(ByteBuffer.allocate(bufSize),
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<HooMEMessage>(Consts.SEND_QUEUE_CAPACITY), false));
}

/**
 * handles read connections for channels
 */
public void handleRead(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    // Client socket channel has pending data
    SocketChannel clntChan = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    ByteBuffer buf = ((HooMEAttachment) key.attachment()).getBuffer();
    buf.flip();
    long bytesRead = clntChan.read(buf);
    if (bytesRead == -1) { // Did the other end close?
        clntChan.close();
    } else if (bytesRead > 0 && !HooMEUtilities.isEmpty(buf.array())) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf.array()));
        InputStream anInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream (buf.array());
        MessageInput anInput = new MessageInput (anInputStream);
        //if we are supposed to receive a handshake 
        if(!((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).getSendHandshake()&&!((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).connectionOk()) {              
            String greeting = null;         
            try {
                System.out.println("got a handshake");
                greeting = anInput.readString();
                anInput.readString();
            } //consume the second new line character

            catch (BadAttributeValueException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(greeting.equals(Consts.HANDSHAKE_GREETING)) {
                key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
            } else {
                //handshake greeting was wrong we will terminate this connection
                key.channel().close();
                key.cancel();
            }

            // if we are supposed to be reading an acknowledgment
        } else if( ((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).getSendHandshake() && !((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).connectionOk()) {
            String response = null;
            try {
                response = anInput.readString();
                if(response.equals(Consts.HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE)) {
                    ((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).setConnectionOk(true);
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);  
                    anInput.readString(); //consume the second newline character
                } else {
                    key.channel().close();
                    key.cancel();
                }
            } catch (BadAttributeValueException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            HooMEMessage aMessage= null;
            try {
                aMessage = HooMEMessage.decode(anInput);  
                //if we have a response sent back
                if(aMessage instanceof HooMEResponse || aMessage.getTtl()>0) { //treat all responses as comcast
                    //look up id of message in the forwarding table
                    for (Entry<byte[], InetAddress> entry : HooMENode.mappingTable.entrySet()) {
                        if(Arrays.equals(aMessage.getId(), entry.getKey())) {  //if we have a mapping for this id in our routing table
                            //loop through our neighbours and find the one we want
                            for(SelectionKey aKey:key.selector().keys()) {
                                if(aKey.channel() instanceof SocketChannel && 
                                        ((SocketChannel)aKey.channel()).socket().getInetAddress()==entry.getValue()) {
                                    aMessage.setTtl(aMessage.getTtl()-1);
                                    ((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).getSendQueue().add(aMessage);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (aMessage instanceof HooMESearch) {   //if a search message has been sent . 
                    //broadcast service requested broadcast the search to all and sundry
                    if(aMessage.getRoutingService().getServiceCode()==0 &&aMessage.getTtl()>0) {
                        aMessage.setTtl(aMessage.getTtl()-1);
                        for(SelectionKey aKey:key.selector().keys()) {
                            if(aKey.attachment()!=null && aKey.attachment() instanceof HooMEAttachment) {
                                ((HooMEAttachment)aKey.attachment()).getSendQueue().add(aMessage);
                            }
                        }

                        //place mapping for the broadcast message in the mapping table
                        HooMENode.mappingTable.put(aMessage.getId(),  ((SocketChannel)key.channel()).socket().getInetAddress());
                    } 

                    //respond to the search
                    List<Result> searchResults = HooMENode.getFileResults(((HooMESearch)aMessage).getSearchString());
                    HooMEMessage response = new HooMEResponse(aMessage.getId(), 1, RoutingService.getRoutingService(1), aMessage.getDestinationHooMEAddress(), aMessage.getSourceHooMEAddress(), 
                            new InetSocketAddress(HooMENode.address,HooMENode.downloadPort));
                    ((HooMEResponse)response).getResultList().addAll(searchResults);
                    ((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).getSendQueue().add(response);
                }
                // Indicate via key that reading/writing are both of interest now.
                key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BadAttributeValueException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}

/**
 * handles write connections for channels
 */
public void handleWrite(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    OutputStream anOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteBuffer buf = ((HooMEAttachment) key.attachment()).getBuffer();
    /*
     * Channel is available for writing, and key is valid (i.e., client channel
     * not closed).
     */

    //we are supposed to send an acknowledgement of a handshake
    if(!((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).getSendHandshake()&&!((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).connectionOk()) { 
        anOutput.write((Consts.HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE+Consts.EOLN+Consts.EOLN).getBytes(HooMEMessage.CHARENCODING));
        //confirm that the connection is ok
        ((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).setConnectionOk(true);
        buf.put(((ByteArrayOutputStream)anOutput).toByteArray());
        SocketChannel clntChan = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        clntChan.write(buf);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf.array()));
        if(!buf.hasRemaining()) {
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);  
        }

        //if we are supposed to be sending an handshake 
    } else if( ((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).getSendHandshake() && !((HooMEAttachment)key.attachment()).connectionOk()) {
        anOutput.write((Consts.HANDSHAKE_GREETING+Consts.EOLN+Consts.EOLN).getBytes(HooMEMessage.CHARENCODING));
        buf.put(((ByteArrayOutputStream)anOutput).toByteArray());
        SocketChannel clntChan = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        clntChan.write(buf);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf.array()));
        if(!buf.hasRemaining()) {
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);  
        }
    } else {
        //check the send queue for messages that can be sent if there are none then do nothing
        HooMEMessage aMessage = ((HooMEAttachment) key.attachment()).getSendQueue().poll();
        if(aMessage != null) {
            MessageOutput aMessageOutput = new MessageOutput(anOutput);
            aMessage.encode(aMessageOutput);            
        }       
        buf.put(((ByteArrayOutputStream)anOutput).toByteArray());
        SocketChannel clntChan = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        clntChan.write(buf);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf.array()));
        if(!buf.hasRemaining()) {
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        }
    }


    // Make room for more data to be read in
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't flip before reading. Flip before writing or getting, and compact or clear afterwards.